# Print Text between two words in a text file multitime using python

Tags: python

This is the text in my text file.

```
<a>
Some Text 1.....
</a>
Some Other Text
<a>
Some Text 2.....
</a>
Some Other Text
<a>
Some Text 3.....
</a>
```

I need to extract string between a tags and write every string in a Separate text file using python 2.7/3.

Bellow code just return The string between First Tag And does not consider the rest of the text.

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as inF:
for num, line in enumerate(inF,1):
    if '</a>' in line:
        targetline = num+1
        f = open("myfile.txt")
        aa = ""
        for i in range(targetline):
            aa += f.next().strip() + "\n"
        f.close()
        fout = open("MyData1.txt", "w")
        finaltext = (aa.split('<a>'))[1].split('</a>')[0]
        fout.write(finaltext)
        fout.close()
```

Do you have any idea to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup`

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(filename, 'r') as f, open(filename1, 'w') as outfile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "html.parser")
    for i in soup.find_all("a"):
        print(i.text.strip())
        outfile.write(i.text.strip() + "\n")     #Write to new File
```

**Output:**

```
Some Text 1.....
Some Text 2.....
Some Text 3.....
```